# jQuery loop through select options and display multiple image

Tags: jquery, loops, html-select

i have a select box which accepts multiple selections ([Bootstrap Select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/)) when an option is selected i want to display an image. The image part i have done! It successfully echo's an image based on the value.

But how do i loop through the options so it shows multiple images when more than 1 option is selected.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#PrimaryTrade").each(function () {
        $(this).on('changed.bs.select', function (e) {
            $("img[name=image-swap]").attr("src","/images/icons/" + $(this).val() + "_Image.png");
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: If the select is multiple, you need to write some dynamic places for the images, so *n* options selected, *n* images you'll obtain

Comment: It is better if you create JsFiddle and post link here.

Comment: Why are you looping through id?
#PrimaryTrade

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context...

Comment: Sorry js-fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/q0stuz19/11/

Answer (score 0):

Using the .val() function on a multi-select list will return an array of the selected values:

```
var selectedValues = $('#multipleSelect').val();
```

After that you can loop through this array and create multiple images like this and add every image to a specific point in the DOM:

```
var img = $('<img />',
             { id: 'ImageId',
               src: 'Image.png', 
               width: 300
             })
              .appendTo($('#YourDiv'));
```

Comment: Sorry i didnt include fiddle - please find fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/q0stuz19/11/